# Store current COUNTIFS value in each row in MS-Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple Excel file with some columns as you can see from here:

http://silvercover.ir/downloads/test.xlsx

I have a simple formula (COUNTIFS) to count occurrence of certain condition that I specified. everything works fine here, but I also need to write current value of count cell at the end of each qualified row.

```
COUNTIFS(F:F;7;G:G;1;H:H;93)
```

Data entry is random and I may work on row 1 and then row 25, so incremental row numbers that is shown by excel is not my answer. I need exact number of occurrence for each qualified row.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Links die with time and as such, the ability to download the Excel file may not be possible; can you edit your post and add the function you're using please?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: This is better but please also copy the formula too - it makes it easier to read etc. It means we can copy the formula direct into Excel to play with it

Comment: =COUNTIFS(F:F;7;G:G;1;H:H;93)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain or show what should be the end result like?

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies, the function works perfectly and will continue to work with blank rows as is.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't get your question wrong, it seems that it can solved simply by doing this:

COUNTIFS($F$1:F1;7;$G$1:G1;1;$H$1:H1;93) - that is for row 1.

If u drag down accordingly, it should give you the count of the rows as we go along